# FirebaseAdmin The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: linux, firebase, docker, asp.net-core, firebase-admin

I have asp.net core API running on docker container the container is running on Linux machine. I use FirebaseAdmin to push notifications to Firebase. If I run the container on my local windows machine it works fine. But if I deploy it to the linux maching I am getting 'FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: The SSL connection could not be established'

Code:

```
    public async Task<BatchResponse> SendNotification(List<string> registrationTokens, PushMessage pushMessage)
    {
        FirebaseApp defaultApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "notificationsKey.json"))
        });
        // Create a list containing up to 500 registration tokens.
        // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
        var message = new MulticastMessage()
        {
            Tokens = registrationTokens,
            Data = pushMessage.Data,
            Notification = pushMessage.Notification,
        };

        BatchResponse response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message);
        // See the BatchResponse reference documentation
        // for the contents of response.
        Console.WriteLine($"{response.SuccessCount} messages were sent successfully");
        return response;
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
    FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendBatchRequestAsync(IEnumerable`1 messages, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAllAsync(IEnumerable`1 messages, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAllAsync(IEnumerable`1 messages, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAllAsync(IEnumerable`1 messages, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendMulticastAsync(MulticastMessage message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendMulticastAsync(MulticastMessage message, Boolean dryRun)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendMulticastAsync(MulticastMessage message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out. Running into the exact same issue on our EC2 servers at the moment. Would be greatly appreciated if you could post a solution